Facebook Graph API Not Returning All Title's and Body For Each Ad
I have a script that pulls in each ad, the thumbnail, title, body and a few other bits into Google Sheets.
I have some responses coming back with the title and body, and some not.
here is the graph api I'm running to try find why, but still coming up short.
act_/ads?fields=id,name,creative,adcreatives{title,body}
I then just get an empty result for some
{
      "id": "< ID >",
      "name": "< AD NAME >",
      "creative": {
        "id": "< ID >"
      },
      "adcreatives": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "< ID>"
          }
        ]
      }
    }

Any idea on why it returns values for some and not others? The ads have those values present in the account.

You can bypass this problem changing the graphql call.
Instead of /<creative_id>?fields=body,name
You can do /<creative_id>?fields=asset_feed_spec
